# Django Article text can't be highlighted or linked

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I'm very new to Python and Django, but am working with a website that uses article models.

The problem I have is that the text inside my articles cannot be highlighted. Not only that, but the links can't be clicked.

My process has been to include an srcUrl under the articles model. I make every article that I write into a HTML document and upload it to a separate directory than my main one. In Django admin I link to that document.

When I go to just the HTML file, the links work. However, when I view the article in my website, it doesn't work:
[HTML File](http://alicelanyang.com/articles/what-does-it-mean-if-i-have-a-stellium.html) | [What it looks like on my site](http://www.alicesparklykat.com/articles/19/)

I'm wondering if this is the best way to do things. I'm worried that, since the content doesn't show up on inspector, that the keywords in my article don't affect my website.

Here is what my models.py looks like:

```
class Article(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
abstract = models.TextField()
imgUrl = models.CharField(max_length=200)
srcUrl = models.CharField(max_length=200)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(
    default=timezone.now)
```

And this is where the content of my articles go in my HTML document:

```
<p class="embed-responsive-item">{{article_content | safe}}</p>
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this so that the text is able to be highlighted and I can add links to the articles? Does anyone know if the way it's currently set up affects SEO?

I feel like I have no idea what I'm doing, so let me know if something I said is confusing!

Comment: Have you considered include a Rich Text Editor, like django-ckeditor (https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor) which gives all the text formatting you could want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be affecting SEO negatively because searching for `What Does It Mean If I Have A Stellium? site:alicesparklykat.com` in Google only yields your homepage and not that page itself- although this may be because the article was posted fairly recently. The reason this is happening is because of the `embed-responsive-item` and `embed-responsive` bootstrap tag. It is not clear why you have chosen to use this methodology instead of just putting the HTML in a subclassed template. Removing both `embed-responsive-item` and `embed-responsive` makes your text function normally.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you mind giving me an example of a subclassed template? I’m not sure what that is.

Comment: The technical term used in the Django docs is template inheritance. It allows you to create a base template and then when creating other templates you only have to specify what's different, rather then rewriting everything. You can read about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance